# selecting multiple checkboxes in separate divs with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have several checkboxes spread across multiple divs.In all separate div I have a 'select all' checkbox. When that checkbox is selected, I am trying to get all the other ones to be selected related to that pertucular div, and when you deselect the 'select all' one, it deselects the others.

```
<div class="actions" id="actions" title="Actions">
   <div>
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="0" /> Select All</div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="1" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][1]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="2" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][2]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="3" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][3]; ?></div><br />

   </div>
   <div>
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="26" />Select All</div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="27" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][27]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="28" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][28]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="29" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][29]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="30" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][30]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="31" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][31]; ?></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

Next time show us at least a minimum of code so that we can help you understand

```js
$('.selectAll').on('click',function(){
  let isSelected = $(this).is(':checked');
  $(this).parents('.myDiv').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    if( isSelected )
      $(this).prop('checked',true);
    else
      $(this).prop('checked',false);
  })
})


$('input:not(".selectAll")').on('click',function(){
  let selectAllChecked =  $(this).parents('.myDiv').find('.selectAll')[0].checked;
  let numberInput = $(this).parents('.myDiv').find('input').not('.selectAll').length;
  let numberInputChecked = $(this).parents('.myDiv').find('input:checked').not('.selectAll').length;
  
  if( selectAllChecked )
    $(this).parents('.myDiv').find('.selectAll')[0].checked = false;
      
  if( numberInput == numberInputChecked)
    $(this).parents('.myDiv').find('.selectAll')[0].checked = true;
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="actions" id="actions" title="Actions">
   <div class="myDiv">
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="selectAll" value="0" /> Select All</div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="1" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][1]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="2" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][2]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="3" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][3]; ?></div><br />

   </div>
   <div class="myDiv">
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="selectAll" value="26" />Select All</div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="27" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][27]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="28" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][28]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="29" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][29]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="30" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][30]; ?></div><br />
       <div><input type="checkbox" name="action" id="" class="" value="31" /> <?php echo $lang["actions"][31]; ?></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you..!! It's working fine. Can we add one more logic in this?? like, if any checkbox is unchecked except the first one which is ".selectAll"  then ".seelectAll" checkbox should automatically uncheck.

Comment: Of course, I edited my code if you want to see